# Creating New Table by select query with sequental column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains column names like this;

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|                              BankTable                             |           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Id | BANK1     | BANK2     | BRANCH1     | BRANCH2     | IBAN1     | IBAN2     |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | BANK1_ID1 | BANK2_ID1 | BRANCH1_ID1 | BRANCH2_ID1 | IBAN1_ID1 | IBAN2_ID1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | BANK1_ID2 | BANK2_ID2 | BRANCH1_ID2 | BRANCH1_ID2 | IBAN1_ID2 | IBAN2_ID2 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

How can i write a query that returns the result like this;

```
 +------------------------------------------+
|                   BANK                   |
+------------------------------------------+
| ID | BANK      | BRANCH      | IBAN      |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | BANK1_ID1 | BRANCH1_ID1 | IBAN1_ID1 |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 2  | BANK2_ID2 | BRANCH1_ID2 | IBAN2_ID2 |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

P.s: I am writing select query by Id column. BTW query result contains one row every time.

Any help appreciated.

**SOLUTION**
I don't know if it's good approach but i solved this by based on @Giorgos Betsos answer. Here is how i fixed this problem.

```
SELECT BANK, BRANCH, IBAN
FROM (
    SELECT BANK1, BANK2, BRANCH1, BRANCH2, IBAN1, IBAN2
    FROM BankTable
    WHERE ID = your_id_here
) AS src
UNPIVOT (
    BANK FOR Col IN(BANK1, BANK2)
) AS unpvt1
UNPIVOT (
    BRANCH FOR Col1 IN(BRANCH1, BRANCH2)
) AS unpvt2
UNPIVOT (
    IBAN FOR Col2 IN(IBAN1, IBAN2)
) AS unpvt3
WHERE RIGHT(Col, 1) = RIGHT(Col1, 1)
    AND RIGHT(Col, 1) = RIGHT(Col2, 1)
```

Comment: Have you tried UNION ALL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT Bank
FROM (
  SELECT Id, BANK1, BANK2, BANK3, BANK4, BANK5
  FROM BankTable
  WHERE id = 1) AS src
UNPIVOT (
  Bank FOR Col IN([BANK1], [BANK2], [BANK3], [BANK4], [BANK5])) AS unpvt
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f696/2)

Comment: Thank you! Well if there was much more than one sequental column name in the table, what can i do?

Comment: @erhanzeyrek In this case I would suggest to have a look at the solution provided by Ullas.

Answer (score 0):

If number of column is more, then you can use a dynamic sql query as below:

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql =stuff(
                (select 'union all select [' + column_name + '] as Bank 
                           from BankTable where Id = 1 ' 
                from information_schema.columns 
                where table_name = 'BankTable'
                and column_name like 'BANK[0-9]%'
                for xml path('')), 1, 9, '');

execute(@sql);
```

**Result**

```
+-----------+
| Bank      |
+-----------+
| BANK1_ID1 |
| BANK2_ID1 |
| BANK3_ID1 |
| BANK4_ID1 |
| BANK5_ID1 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But what i put to 'column_name' area? My BankTable's column names are like this "BANK1, BANK2, BANK3... BANK 7, BANKBRANCH1, BANKBRANCH2, BANKBRANCH3..., BANKBRANCH7"

Comment: Does not return any results. Only commands commands completed successfully. Can you take a look my query?

Comment: @erhanzeyrek : You have to execute the query using `execute(@sql)`

Comment: Does not return any results. Only returns "commands commands completed successfully". Also i want to create a new column named BANKBRANCH sequental BANKBRANCH1...BANKBRANCH7 columns.

`declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql =stuff(
                (select 'union all select [' + column_name + '] as Bank 
                           from BankTable where Id = 320.A472 ' 
                from DBNAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                where table_name = 'BankTable'
                and column_name like 'BANK[0-9]%'
                for xml path('')), 1, 9, '');

execute(@sql);`

Comment: @erhanzeyrek : please remove DBNAME before `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.